# custom SimpleCursorAdapter and BindView (buttons are randomly Invisible)

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, simplecursoradapter

I made custom SimpleCursorAdapter so i can click on button inside ListView (the button needs to call someone) when there is no phone number i want the button to be invisible, at first my code show everything correctly but when i scroll up and down few times buttons are randomly become invisible.

edited: when all of them visible it's fine but when one (button inside item on ListView) become invisible they starts to randomly become invisible.

my code:

```
 public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, double lat, double lon) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    latC = lat;
    lonC = lon;
}

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_place_list, parent, false);
        return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view,final Context context,final Cursor cursor) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesDB.PLACE_NAME));
    String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesDB.PLACE_ADDRESS));
    double lat = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesDB.PLACE_LAT));
    double lon = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesDB.PLACE_LON));
    final String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PlacesDB.PLACE_PHONE));

    TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView txtAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    TextView txtDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDistance);

    txtName.setText(name);
    txtAddress.setText(address);

    Button btnCall = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
    if (latC != -1) {
        double dis = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(latC, lonC, lat, lon);
        if (settings.getString("mk", "km").equals("miles")) {
            dis = dis / 1.621371;
            txtDistance.setText(String.format("%.3f", dis) + " Miles");
        }
        else
            txtDistance.setText(String.format("%.3f", dis) + " Km");
    } else {
        txtDistance.setText("Distance not available");
    }
    if (phone == null){
        btnCall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnCall).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tel;
                Intent dialIntent = new Intent();
                tel = phone.replace("-", "");
                dialIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tel));
                context.startActivity(dialIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since android tries to recycle unused listview-items you always have to set all gui elements

```
if (phone == null){
    btnCall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

only made btnCall invisible but there is no code to make a recycled invisible listview-item-btnCall visible again.

```
if (phone == null){
    btnCall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    btnCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

should do the job.

For the same reason the code for `view.findViewById(R.id.btnCall).setOnClickListener(...)`
should be execeted in `newView()` so it is added only once.